# What does `Control.refine` do in Ltac2?

Tags: coq

I'm learning Ltac2 and reading the [official documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac2.html) of coq 8.13.2.

I do not get what role `Control.refine` play in the evaluation inside of quotations, as there doesn't seem to be a lot of explanations to this function.

For example, using variables in tactic expressions inside a `constr` quotation should be done by: `constr:(... $x ...)`, where `$x` is the syntactic sugar of `ltac2:(Control.refine (fun () => x))`.

Why does, say simply, `ltac2:(x)` not work? (and it indeed doesn't, as coq gives an error of `Error: Cannot infer an existential variable of type ...`, at the position where the constr represented by `x` should be inserted).

So my questions are:

1. What does `Control.refine` do in general?
2. It seems to be an idiom to sometimes do this: `constr:( ... ltac2:(Control.refine (fun () => ...) ...)`, in what situation where such anti-quotation idiom should (or shouldn't) be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ltac2:(...)` in-term quotation expects an Ltac2 term of type `unit`, not of type `constr`. Actually, your example should trigger a warning because of this.

Since the content of the quotation has type `unit`, it means that it can only act through side-effects. The warning tells you that the value returned by the quotation will be discarded. In particular, it cannot be used to fill the hole.

Rather, the semantics of the quotation is to evaluate its content inside a goal `Γ ⊢ A` where `Γ` is the current list of hypotheses, and `A` the inferred type of the hole. It is expected that doing this will solve the goal, and the resulting partial proof will be used as the Coq term filler for that hole. This is precisely the rôle of `Control.refine : (unit -> constr) -> unit`. It takes a (for technical reasons, thunked) term as an argument and uses it to solve the goal(s) under focus.

What happens in your example is that you provide a term that is just ignored, the goal is left untouched and the quotation rightfully complains that it was not solved.

Regarding your second point, I cannot really tell. It depends on what you want do do. But in general, if you stick to antiquotations `$x` I would consider this more readable. It is not always possible to do so, though, e.g. if the term being built depends on a context introduced in the `constr:(...)` quotation.